# Why after installing Android Studio on Windows 10 I don't need to install JDK? Is it already there?

Tags: java, android

I have used android studio on windows 7, every time I install android studio I had to install jdk and configure environment path first . but in windows 10 when I installed android studio it didn't ask me for jdk and I can use android studio without any problem I also installed an app in my mobile everything works fine.

I went to cmd to check if jdk is installed I type java -version and javac but both came up with error.

If the JDK is not installed then how come android studio is working?

Comment: (Down-voters please comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some time now Android Studio includes its own private java runtime in jre folder.

Comment: So if I try to install same android studio version on windows 7 there will be no need to install jdk ?

Comment: Exactly. External JDK is not required anymore, actually it is recommended to always use embedded JDK.

Comment: So what do I set for JAVA_HOME then?

Comment: If someone wanted to run Android Studio IDE on a custom JavaJDK then this trick should work without affecting an installation or creating a global javaenv console variables. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70988256/185565