# Jar file not execute in ubuntu while Android studio is work perfectly

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

Android studio is working perfectly but while i am executing jar file

```
java -jar file_name.jar
```

but jar file not execute in this case what is going wrong. Any suggestion

[image: Here is a screen shot]

Comment: Is there any error message? It would be helpful if you posted it.

Comment: did you specified main class of application while creating jar file.

Comment: bm@bm-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ java -jar gdx.jar
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
Sorry for late!
Problem is that "Android Studio" work perfect java installed jre also but facing this problem :(

Answer (score 1):

You do not have java in your path. If you already have java installed, add its location to your path environment variable. If you do not already have java installed, follow the suggestion in the error message you received to install it.

Comment: Please suggest some related information how i specify the java path??I have java that's why i am enable to run Android Studio in OS!

Comment: How did you install java? Being able to run android studio does not mean you have java separately installed, since android studio comes with its own JDK bundled (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172010/do-i-need-java-jdk-for-using-android-studio).